# How to train a recurrent neural network with multiple series

Tags: neural-networks, recurrent-neural-networks

I am new to neural networks. I am trying to model the run-off vs. time in a water channel after a storm event given that I know the permeability of the material in the channel, total precipitation, and some other single valued parameters for a particular event..

I have a database of run off histories, and the values of the associated parameters (permeability, total precipitation, etc)

I want my model to give me a runoff vs. Time history when I enter the associated parameters.

I do not know how to train my model. Do i just stack all the time histories in my database together and feed them together? All examples in books use one time history to train the model. Im confused.

Comment: This seems like a regression problem. Are you just trying to map N independant variables (percipitation etc.) to two dependant variables (time and run-off)?